# Why is div unclickable when using relative positioning?

Tags: css, css-position

I am currently designing a website for a business to build computers.

The only problem is, the site only works 100% in Firefox. My current problem is that the `div` on the left (with the pictures) and the div on the right (with the Facebook like box) are unclickable in every browser except Firefox. I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the `z-index`, but I don't know how to fix it.

What I have is a navbar at the top with a main div with relative positioning. Inside this main div I have 3 more `div`s. One for each column of the page, left, middle, and right. None of these `divs` are clickable however and this is the CSS code I have:

```css
#fr {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 290px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 45px;
}

#la {
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 92.5%;
  left: 15px;
  top: 45px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

#maindata {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

#main {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

What can I do to fix this? I would be willing to share my source (it is coded in PHP but it is mostly HTML.

Comment: Yo Kyle, we'll be happy to help you if you revise your question to follow the guidelines of the website. [Take a read here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to see what's wrong with your question and how you can fix it.

Comment: Just a quick tip: if you also post a jsFiddle demo with your question, you will get better quality and quicker answers, because it is easier for the people who want to help you to play with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do `#main` and `#la` have `z-index: -1` on them? This puts them behind the `body` (or some other element) so they are not reachable via hover/click actions. Remove these styles and the page will work fine.

Comment: I did this in a test page here: [link](http://infinixbuilds.us/ind.php) and it did not seem to make a difference :/

Comment: @KyleBoyer Sorry, I did something else while testing and forgot I had done it. I'll amend my post.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the that problem, but along the same links on the same link I posted above, now my menu is un-folding behind the images. How/Where would I set this z-index to the highest possible?

Edit: Nevermind, I fixed it! I just added a style to my ul for my menu. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleBoyer Set `#topnav`'s `z-index` to something 2+. Edit: Glad you got it! ;)